# jquery: when i click a div, give focus to a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, focusin

```
$('.my-button').click(function() {
    $(".my-textbox").focus()
});
```

Before Jquery 1.4 this used to be the way to call focus to a textbox, now it doesn't work. When I click the button, I want to call focus to the textbox, what i mean by "focus", is that I want the textbox to act like it was just clicked on, so that the user will not have to click on the textbox.

`.focus` is supposed to do an auto click onto the textbox i want it to, why isn't it working now? it broke in Jquery 1.4. I just need to know how to do it.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in 1.4.2 - http://jsfiddle.net/DpQkG/

Comment: focus() is a regular JavaScript method. Are you sure there isn't a mistake in your code? focus() works as it always has regardless of jQuery version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It still works. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aVsxr/1/).

reference: [jQuery focus docs](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

As mentioned there, calling 'focus' on one element may trigger 'blur' on another - and so use 'focusin' instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your code [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/DpQkG/).  However, it looks like you're trying to create a clickable label for an input element.  If that's the case, there's an existing element named `<label>` that will do the job for you, no JavaScript required:

```
<label for="myTextBox">I'm a label, click me</label>
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pkk6y/**

Answer (score 2):

Those are class selectors not IDs - not sure if that's relevant, but they're inherently not unique - particularly in the focus function jquery may just plain refuse - try using IDs (and #mybutton, #mytextbox)

Update: The jQuery [doc page](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) points out issues with IE:

> The focus event does not bubble in
>   Internet Explorer. Therefore, scripts
>   that rely on event delegation with the
>   focus event will not work consistently
>   across browsers.